# IOException (MAIN_THREAD) using InstanceID and ReactiveX

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, rx-android

I am following [this architecture](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture) to build an app.

I want to get a device's GCM token and send it to my server. This is the line where the exception is thrown:

```
String token = instanceID.getToken(Constants.SENDER_ID,
                   GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

As I amb using [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid), I don't understand why this happens because this line is executed in a new thread. I even make requests to my server synchronously and everything works fine.

How I configure the Rx:

```
public class RegisterGcmUseCase {

  private Subscription subscription = Subscriptions.empty();

  public void execute(Subscriber UseCaseSubscriber) {
    this.subscription = this.buildUseCaseObservable()
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe(UseCaseSubscriber);
  }

  public Observable buildUseCaseObservable() {

    // ...

    InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(context);
    String token = "";

    try {
        token = instanceID.getToken(Constants.SENDER_ID,
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // ...

  }
}
```

Any idea of what's happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is thrown because you're calling instanceID.getToken on the main thread and that's not allowed. Calling this method in a background thread will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough detail of *how* the Observable is constructed in `buildUseCaseObservable()`.  I suspect that `instanceID.getToken(...)` is still being invoked when the Observable is created, which happens on the main thread.

My suggestion is to rather construct the Observable using the `defer()` operator, which will construct the Observable on subscriptions.